# ruby/rails sort an array of records based on an array of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array of user records, and I would like to sort the users based on priority, which is stored in an array of strings and this array is always changing.

so if i have
users =

```
    User id: 1, username: "so_admin", priority: "Monday"

    User id: 2, username: "so_staff", priority: "Wednesday"
```

priority = ["Wednesday","Tuesday","Friday"]

How can I sort my users so that users where their priority is "Wednesday" are listed first, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do as

```
users.sort_by { |u| priority.index(u.priority) || priority.size }
```

The above sorting is done, with the assumption that the below `Array` will be sorted as per your need, will hold all *uniq* values. `users` array then will use the index of the sorted array.

```
priority = ["Wednesday","Tuesday","Friday"]
```

[`index(obj) → int or nil`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-index)

> Returns the *index* of the first object in `ary` such that the object is `==` to `obj`. Returns `nil` if *no match is found*.

`priority` array doesn't hold all weekdays, rather `3`. I thought, if any users has *priority*, which is not present in the `priority` array, let those users be placed in the last array. Suppose, for any user there is a *priority*, `"Sunday"`, then, that user will be given *lowest priority*. How ?

Look at the expression `priority.index(u.priority) || priority.size`, now with above mentioned sample, `priority.index("sunday")` gives `nil`, and *right hand side* expression of the `||` will be evaluated, i.e. `priority.size`, which `3`. That's how that `user` will be moved to the *tail* of the *array*.

Comment: wonderful! this worked! thank you! Would you mind explaining what the "priority.size" part does?